# Trash a post, send associated comments into the trash bin (change status)

Tags: posts, comments, trash

When trashing a post, all comments associated with this post get the status "post-trashed". They do not end up in the trash bin.

In my theme the author gets a point for posting a post or a comment. Subsequently I also want to deduct a point when the posts or comments is trashed.

Both of these functions works excellent. The problem arise when I trash a post. I want the associated comments to also be affected, and have one point reduced.

This function: http://de.wpseek.com/wp_trash_post_comments/ seems to be the culprit. So I think the best solution is to either somehow force the "post_comments" to be sent into the actual trash bin, or somehow incorporate an action to the above function to also remove a point when trashing "post_comments". (it would be important that there is no conflict with trash_comment, so the action somehow doesn't get called twice, and reduces two point for one comment being trashed).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's an action called `trashed_post_comments` that runs right after the comments are set to `post-trashed` status. You could hook into that:

```
add_action( 'trashed_post_comments', 'wpse134528_really_trash_comments' );
function wpse134528_really_trash_comments( $post_id ) {
    $args = array( 
        'post_id' => $post_id,
        'status' => 'post-trashed',
    );
    $comments = get_comments( $args );
    foreach( $comments as $comment ) {
        wp_trash_comment( $comment->comment_id );
    }
}
```

#### References

- [`trashed_post_comments`](http://wpseek.com/hook/trashed_post_comments/) action hook
- [`get_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments)
- [`wp_trash_comment()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/comment.php#L1213)

Hopefully this helps, though I'm not sure I understand why comments with their status set to `post-trashed` would be messing up your theme...

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to get that function to work. My theme is using a point system. Author get points when posting posts and comments. And when the posts or comments are removed (thrown in the trash), the user get one point deducted (this is done with a update_user_meta function along with the actions wp_trash_post and trash_comment). The problem is when I trash a post, the attached comments are not affected because they get the post-trashed status. At least I think this is the reason why it doesnt work.

Comment: You might want to update your question with *all* the details.

Comment: I've updated the question. I'd appreciate if you have a look at it once more!

Comment: Any ideas, Pat J?